# Print location and value of all non-zero entries of a SciPy CSR matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I would like to print the location and value of the non-zero entries of a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`.

Currently, only 50 entries are printed. One can query this value with the `getmaxprint()` method.

You can write a naive function to print out something similar, e.g.

```
def print_all_entries(A):
    Acoo = A.tocoo()
    for [r,c,v] in  zip(Acoo.row,Acoo.col,Acoo.data):
        print('(',r,',',c,') ',v,sep='')
```

Can I print the location and value of all the non-zero entries of a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` without resorting to writing my own print function?

Answer (score 2):

One can directly set the `maxprint` field

```
A.maxprint = numpy.inf
print(A)
```

Answer (score -1):

What about `nonzero`?
This method gives the locations of non-zero elements:

```
>>> A.nonzero()
(array([0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8], dtype=int32),
 array([5, 7, 1, 6, 8, 3, 0, 6, 8, 3], dtype=int32))
```

You can zip these locations as following:

```
>>> list(zip(*A.nonzero()))
[(0, 5),
 (0, 7),
 (2, 1),
 (3, 6),
 (3, 8),
 (5, 3),
 (6, 0),
 (6, 6),
 (6, 8),
 (8, 3)]
```

And get the values with:
    A[A.nonzero()]

Example:

```
>>> A=random(10, 10, format='csr', density=0.1)
>>> A[A.nonzero()]
matrix([[0.85540452, 0.21215213, 0.1745446 , 0.92454695, 0.65243625,
         0.65773299, 0.01331784, 0.00839577, 0.52288882, 0.90532361]])
```

[Update] To get also the locations of the elements:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: list(x)+[A[x]], zip(*A.nonzero())))
[[0, 5, 0.8554045197549517],
 [0, 7, 0.21215213256670906],
 [2, 1, 0.17454460028283592],
 [3, 6, 0.9245469548294805],
 [3, 8, 0.6524362523417645],
 [5, 3, 0.6577329931141327],
 [6, 0, 0.013317838205963661],
 [6, 6, 0.008395774209458584],
 [6, 8, 0.5228888210996887],
 [8, 3, 0.9053236095777115]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but you've written a custom print function in a functional style. The question is asking about doing this without having to write a special function.